# How to adjust div elements width for different screen size?

Tags: css, html

I'm working on SPA and I tried to avoid using tables for non tabular data. On my main page I have set of elements and I need them to be in side-by-side order. For this I used class:

```
div.nextTo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

This looks fine and works on the big screen. Once I resized my browser or if I open my app on Mobile device my elements are sitting over each other. I also set the width in percentage for each element and seems that doesn't adjust on the different screen size. Here is example:

```css
div.pgContainer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
div.headerBox {
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 2px solid #000099;
 border-right: 2px solid #000099;
 border-left: 2px solid #000099;
 height: 25px;
 background-color: #000099;
}
div.headerBox span {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 font-size: 16px;
}
section.mainBox{
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 0;
 float: left;
 background-color: white;
 border: 2px solid #000099;
}
nav.xNavigation {
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 padding-top: 2px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 background-color: #c8e2db;
 float: left;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
 height: 18px;
}
nav.xNavigation a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
}
nav.xNavigation a:hover {
 color: #999999;
}
div.nextTo {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pgContainer">
  <div class="headerBox">
   <div style="float:left; margin-left:5px;">
    <span>My App</span>
   </div>
   <div style="float:right; margin-right:5px; margin-top:2px;">
    <span>Choose:
     <select name="hmMenu" id="hmMenu">
      <option value="mainBox" selected="selected">Home</option>
      <option value="settingsBox">Settings</option>
     </select>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <section class="mainBox">
   <div id="frmContainer">
    <nav class="xNavigation">
     <a href="#" id="chDemo">Demographic</a> |
     <a href="#" id="adInfo">Adult</a> |
    </nav>
    <form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" action="hmHome.cfm" method="POST" onsubmit="return false">
     <div class="nextTo" style="width:5%;">
      <select name="studMenu" id="studMenu">
       <option value="1">Name</option>
       <option value="2">DOB</option>
       <option value="3">Age</option>
       <option value="4">State</option>
      </select>
     </div>
     <div class="nextTo" style="width:10%;">
      <input type="text" name="searchFld" id="searchFld" size="24" maxlength="24" value="" title="Maximum size of the field is 24 characters." placeholder="Example: John, Miller" />
     </div>
     <div class="nextTo" style="width:5%;">
      <input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search"/>
     </div>
     <div class="nextTo" style="width:30%;">
      <span id="searchMsg" style="display:none;"></span>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I'm wondering what is the best way to make my container adjustable for different screen size? Also what I should use for that in order to work on all browsers? If anyone knows how this can be achived please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: You're looking for a CSS grid framework, but this is off topic for Stack Overflow as it is too broad to be a *practical, answerable problem* ref: [How do I ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There are mane CSS grid frameworks available, so do a Google search and see which might suit your requirements

Comment: I'm not sure why this is too broad since I showed the code and specified the problem....

Comment: That's not enough for the question you are asking - your question is much too broad regardless of how much code you include.  Its almost like asking "I have this design for a web page, how to I make it work?" - there is no definitive or simple answer. There are *many* frameworks available, they all have their own pros and cons. We cannot recommend one for you, nor tell you how to implement it in your code.

Comment: I'm not asking someone to give me a code. All I need is suggestion what could be a good fit. I don't understand why question is down voted.

Comment: My suggestion, as I have already provided, is to use a CSS grid framework. A recommendation as to which one is beyond the scope of this site and is off topic.

Comment: Anyway. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I'd want to suggest that third-party frameworks are looking a bit old-fashioned in August 2017. We've had responsive units like `vw`, `vh`, `vmax` and `vmin` for ages, `@media queries` forever, `flexbox` for a couple of years now and `CSS Grid Layout` since March 2017.

Comment: @Rounin That is exactly my point.There are just so many ways to achieve what the OP is asking, that I cannot see how it can be answered without it falling into the "*primarily opinion-based*" category - which makes the question off-topic. I wasn't suggesting 3rd party solutions, I was using "framework" in the general sense of the word, as an all-encompassing term for the numerous "grid-type options" (whatever the correct term for them is as a whole) such as those you mentioned, or even third-party ones. There are too many potential answers for it *not* to be opinion-based IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You could use @media css rule and define different style attributes depending on the viewport size. Please see this [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). @media browser compatibility can be verified [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=%40media).

Comment: Thank you! This might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `width` using a responsive unit like `vw`.

`1vw` is 1% of the viewport width.

So, if you wanted five elements to span the width of the viewport, you could style the elements something like this:

```
div {
    width: 18vw;
    margin: 1vw;
}
```